# Simulink differential equation, sampling time?

Tags: simulink

I have a circular movement which I want to simulate. I start with the equation phi, and then I want to transform the result into x and y coordinates for the next differential equation.

But here comes the problem: when I transform the signal it becomes a zig-zag-pattern not a normal sinus curve.

appendix:

1. circular movement
2. differential eq
3. "transform phi to x signa"
4. result

Differential eq (Übersetzter Weg means transformer):

[image]

[Image: circular movement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OeOEA.jpg)

[Image: transformation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HciD8.jpg)

[Image: wave](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4SOJ.jpg)

Comment: sorry i am new in simuink how, can i get the code of a simulink simulation?

Comment: OK, I figured out that the diagram is the code, and it's easier to see now. (I'm completely unfamiliar with this, BTW).